# What is the correct way of using specular and gloss textures made by 3DCoat 4.5 "Smart Materials" in Cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I textured a detail in 3DCoat using a 3DCoat new feature called "Smart Materials". I exported a color/specular/gloss maps. I'm trying to replicate the look i get in 3DCoat inside Cycles render with the textures i got, but failing to do so.

What is the correct node setup to get results close to what i see in 3DCoat?

Comment: It would really be helpful to see both a screenshot of how the textured mesh appears in 3DCoat, as well as what the outputted colour/spec/gloss maps look like. If you feel comfortable providing a .blend or .obj file of the mesh as well that would also help us help you? :)